# How do I delete specific rows from each group of a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv data file that I want to process with python pandas. I want to firstly group the data based on their id. Then I want to delete the 4 smallest number in each group. Is there a way to do this?

So far I've tried:

```
if args.process_log:
    datafile = pd.read_csv(args.out_log) 
    grouped_data = datafile.groupby('id')
    datagroup_smallest = grouped_data.apply(lambda x: x.nsmallest(n=4, columns='width'))
    unwanted_index = datagroup_smallest.index.get_level_values(1)
```

Then I want to delete the unwanted rows with their index. I've tried:

```
data_splitted = grouped_data.filter(unwanted_index)
```

I got:

```
TypeError: 'Int64Index' object is not callable
```

Comment: The word you're looking for is `drop`, not `filter`.

Answer (score 1):

Consider [**`DataFrame.groupby.nth`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.nth.html):

```py
data_splitted = grouped_data.nth[:-4]
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice but the 4 smallest numbers are not in order, which means they might not be the first 4 elements in the group.

Comment: Then, run `sort_values` on id and column(s) of interest before `groupby`. Without [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/1422451), I cannot know what such columns are.